# How do I take user input both by typing and by sliding?

Tags: android

New to Android dev. 
I have a number the user is supposed to update, I would like to let the user use the keyboard for input but also (and that would be the primer use case) to put his finger on the number and move it up to increase it or down to decrease it (maybe right and left too). 
[image: Example]
How do I go about accomplishing this?

Best,

Asher

P.S.
I am setting a number within a ListView item, so I need the screen not to scroll while I am doing that..

Comment: what you actually want...please show as image

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a wrong thing to do within a ListView. Imagine having 100 rows there. You would have to scroll vertically in order to see all the rows, but you would also be able to scroll vertically in order to change the volume as well. Not sure if that's possible (I think the listView captures the onTouch event, so you would never be able to get it in the individual fields within each row) and it's also not that intuitive if you ask me. If you have very few elements (very few rows), I would recommend using a LinearLayout and an OnTouchListener on the elements you want to change (the ones on the right on your picture). When you get the onTouch event, make sure is a swipe up or swipe down and do whatever you want with it. Now if you have several rows, I'd recommend rethinking your UI completely (maybe not have an editable field but a horizontal slider?)

Comment: Thanks for replying, there are many items (potentially). The number to the right is the only data to be changed, and it will change on many of the items. I would like give the user an easy - slider style - option but the user expects to see the number changing, not an approximate slider. Maybe vertical scroll?

Comment: You mean horizontal scroll? Either way, Sliding a number seems inherently wrong. Why not try a [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) and display a dialog or a textview next to it with the changing number, as you change it?

Comment: A SeekBar is what I am looking for, but I don't want it showing all the time. Just when it is being used to change the items value.